# What does backslash do in this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does the backslashes do below in the jquery wrapper.

```
div.wrap("<div id=\"wrap-" + id + "\" class=\"" + params.classname + "_wrapper\">")
```

Answer (score 7):

It escapes the quotes inside the string.

`"` starts and ends the string, if you want to use them in the string itself then they need to be escaped.

Answer (score 6):

A JavaScript string delimited with double quotes (`"`) cannot include another double-quote unless it is escaped:

```
// This is wrong
var name = "Phrogz "Broken" Syntax";

// This is right
var name = "Phrogz \"Fixed\" Syntax";

// Or this
var name = 'Phrogz "Simpler" Syntax';
```

The code you posted is the same as this (simpler) version:

```
div.wrap('<div id="wrap-' + id + '" class="' + params.classname + '_wrapper">');
```

Even clearer, though, is this:

```
var wrapD = $('<div>', { id:"wrap-"+id, className:params.classname+"_wrapper" });
div.wrap(wrapD);
```

Answer (score 5):

The backslashes are escaping the double-quotes so that they don't terminate the [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#String_Literals) too early.

At runtime the string won't contain those backslashes and may look something like this, for example:

```
<div id="wrap-1" class="foo_wrapper">
```

Answer (score 2):

It's for escaping the quotation mark inside the string